# Change Font Color by bracket

Tags: html, css

How to change the color of a word between brackets using css and javascript?
example :

```
I am [newbi] programmer
```

I want the word `newbi` to be red or anything

Thanks.

Comment: There are multiple ways of achieving this but without any context i.e. code it is hard to tell what is required. A simple method would be to wrap your text in span elements as you are creating the content i.e. I am <span class='bracketed''>[newbie]</span> programmer. Then in your css file just define the class bracketed to whatever you require.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var match = $('p#sample').html().match(/[^[]+(?=\])/g);
console.log(match);

$.each(match, function( index, value ) {

$('p#sample').html($('p#sample').html().replace("["+value+"]", "<span>"+value+"</span>"));
});
```

```css
span{
color:#F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="sample">Iam [newbi] programmer. This is color [red] </p>
```

Try this

Comment: hi wils thank you for your response, I mean, every word between brackets automatically turns red, but only words while brackets are not visible, tks

Comment: updated with new answer, now it will automatically swap [ ] to red color.

Answer (score 1):

```
span{
  color:#F00;
}
Iam [<span>newbi</span>] programmer
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make it so the HTML itself reads the brackets and instantly knows how to put a certain style on it, that would probably require javascript. As answered before, you can use the `<span>` tag to style a specific part of the text, and add a class to it so you could use different colors for example.

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
Iam <span class="red">newbi</span> programmer. <br>
<span class="blue">Iam</span> newbi programmer. <br>
Iam newbi <span class="yellow">programmer.</span> <br>
<span class="red">Iam </span><span class="blue">a newbi </span><span class="yellow"> programmer.</span>
```